# Lookups in list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, lookup, skip-list

I read about lookups in lists and I think that is what I did. I would like to compare it to a skip list, a binary search or a B+ tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node {
    int node_id;
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;


node *newNode(int data, int node_id) {
    node *new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->node_id = node_id;
    new_node->right = new_node->left = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

node *insert_node(node *root, int data, int node_id) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return newNode(data, node_id);
    else {
        node *cur;
        if (node_id < root->node_id) {
            cur = insert_node(root->left, data, node_id);
            root->left = cur;
        } else if (node_id > root->node_id) {
            cur = insert_node(root->right, data, node_id);
            root->right = cur;
        }
    }
    return root;
}


node *find_node_data(node *root, int node_id) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (root->node_id == node_id)
        return root;
    else if (root->node_id > node_id)
        return find_node_data(root->left, node_id);
    else
        return find_node_data(root->right, node_id);
}

void print(node *np) {
    if (np) {
        print(np->left);
        printf("(%d, %d)", np->node_id, np->data);
        print(np->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int T = 1000; //test case 1000 nodes
    int data, node_id;
    //printf("Input number of nodes:");
    //scanf("%d", &T);
    node *root = NULL;
    srand (time (NULL));
    while (T-- > 0) {
        //printf("Input data. %d:", T);
        //scanf("%d %d", &data, &node_id);
        int r = rand() % 1000;
        int r2 = rand() % 1000;
        root = insert_node(root, r, r2);
    }
    print(root);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Find data at node:", T);
    scanf("%d", &T);
    printf("node data %d", find_node_data(root, T)->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This *is* a binary search tree.
- Do not cast the return value of `malloc`. It serves no purpose, and may mask a serious bug (in case `stdlib.h` is not included).
- Lookup is usually implemented iteratively:

  ```
  while (root) {
      if (root->id == id) {
          break;
      }
      root = (root->id < id)? root->right: root->left;
  }
  return root;
  ```
- **`insert_node`** may use less indentation. Early return makes `else` unnecessary:

  ```
  node *insert_node(node *root, int data, int node_id) {
      if (root == NULL)
          return newNode(data, node_id);
      node *cur;
      if (node_id < root->node_id) {
          cur = insert_node(root->left, data, node_id);
          root->left = cur;
      } else if (node_id > root->node_id) {
          cur = insert_node(root->right, data, node_id);
          root->right = cur;
      }
      return root;
  }
  ```
- You may want to inform the caller that the insertion failed due to `id` already present.

Comment: I thought you had to cast the return of a malloc() or is that just C++?

Comment: @LokiAstari Just C++. In C converting `void *` back and forth to any other pointer is safe.

Answer (score 3):

What @vnp said plus

### newNode()

You have to check that `malloc()` worked:

```
node *newNode(int data, int node_id) {
    node *new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    // Its quite possible for malloc to fail so you need to check
    // and only assign if the malloc worked (otherwise segfault probably).
    if (new_node)
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->node_id = node_id;
        new_node->right = new_node->left = NULL;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

### insert_node()

Early return does not need an else part.
Also the extra `cur` variable is superfolous and does not make it any easier to read.

Which leads to this:

```
node *insert_node(node *root, int data, int node_id) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return newNode(data, node_id);
    }


    if (node_id < root->node_id) {
        root->left = insert_node(root->left, data, node_id);
    } else if (node_id > root->node_id) {
        root->right = insert_node(root->right, data, node_id);
    }

    return root;
}
```

But we know that the `newNode()` can potentially fail. So why go to all the problem of cascading threw the tree if `newNode()` will eventually fail. So you may as well do this up front and then only try and add the node if you can allocate it.

```
node *insert_node(node *root, int data, int node_id) {
    node *item = newNode(data, nodeId);
    return item ? insert_node_data(root, item) : root;
}
node* insert_node_data(node* root, node* item) {
    if (!root) {
        return item;
    }
    // I think you get the idea
}
```